# Blender 2.8 Custom Orientations

Tags: transform-orientation

I'd like to create a Custom Orientation and I'm looking for the little "+" sign in the Orientations dialogue box but it's not there.

I notice that if I click where it should be, Blender does create a new orientation.
Second question: How do I delete a Custom Orientations?

Kind Regards

Michael

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally, the + sign is there. Could you upload an image of the dialog box you're talking about?

Comment: Hi Lemon
I've added an image in my question.

Comment: Hi. Can you confirm you're using official release? (2.80.75) as this + symbol does not seem to have any condition to be displayed.

Comment: Hi Lemon
Yes sir. Downloaded it just a few hours ago.

Comment: As you have clicked blindly and it works. Maybe a display only problem. To delete, select the orientation, a line with its name will appear on the bottom. Click on the right of it (this line in the bottom) to delete the orientation.

Comment: Hi again Lemon
I've attached the right click-menu and there is no option to delete.
The situation is the same for another PC I have.

Comment: Just seen your edit: the cross to delete should be at the bottom right. Use left click on it. Add a second custom orientation to see clearly what is happening when selecting one of them.

Comment: Could be the theme. My mum once set word text colour to white, after that all her documents were blank. Took a long time to work it out over the phone.

Comment: @batFINGER, we all share the same issues, it seems : )

Comment: Hi all

batFINGER was right: It all about the theme. The dark theme looks as it should, plus sign, X and all.
In Blender Light they're missing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a screen capture that can help to localize the icons:

[image]

I think you should try to reinstall and report a bug if this does not fix the issue.